# Why does unzip deletes the content of an object

Tags: python, zip

Could anyone explain to me, why unzipping a zipped object (z1) leaves the initial object (z1) empty?

```
mutants = ['charles xavier', 'bobby drake',
           'kurt wagner', 'max eisenhardt', 'kitty pride']
powers = ['telepathy', 'thermokinesis',
'teleportation', 'magnetokinesis', 'intangibility']

z1 = zip(mutants, powers)

print(*z1)

print(*z1)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterator, and you can only consume an iterator once.

If the number of elements is small, you could create a list or tuple with the elements, or you could use [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to create several independent iterators from the original:

```
import itertools

z1, z2 = itertools.tee(zip(mutants, powers), 2)

print(*z1)
print(*z2)
```

Result:

```
('charles xavier', 'telepathy') ('bobby drake', 'thermokinesis') ('kurt wagner', 'teleportation') ('max eisenhardt', 'magnetokinesis') ('kitty pride', 'intangibility')
('charles xavier', 'telepathy') ('bobby drake', 'thermokinesis') ('kurt wagner', 'teleportation') ('max eisenhardt', 'magnetokinesis') ('kitty pride', 'intangibility')
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't delete it.

If you execute `print(z1)`, you will see that it prints a *zip object*. This is because `zip` does not create a `tuple` or a `list`, but rather an *iterator*.

An iterator is something that generates values on demand. In this case, the zip object generates pairs taken from the input; namely, the `mutants` and `powers` lists. To see this in action, after you assign `z1`, you can call `print(next(z1))`, which causes `z1` to generate the next pair and print it; in this case, `('charles xavier', 'telepathy')`.

If you keep calling `next(z1)`, it will iterate through the two lists until it reaches the end. At that point, it has no data left to read, so if you try calling `next(z1)` again, it will raise the `StopIteration` exception, which signifies that the iterable is *exhausted*.

Conversely, if you did something like `t1 = tuple(z1)`, you would be able to call `print(*t1)` as many times as you wanted. However, if you did that and then tried to call `t2 = tuple(z1)`, you would realise that `t2` was empty. This is for the same reason as the above: building `t1` from `z1` has already exhausted it, so when `t2` tries to get values from `z1`, it immediately hits `StopIteration` and so generates an empty `tuple`.